# Apply transformation for Tensor without including it in Backward

Tags: python, pytorch, backpropagation, tensor

Let's say I have `n` layered neural network. After running `l` layers, I want to apply some transformation to the `l`^th layer output, without including that transformation in backpropagation.

For e.g. :

```
output_layer_n = self.LinearLayer(output_layer_prev)
#apply some transformation to output_layer_n, but don't want to take autograd w.r.t. this transformation, basically this transformation function doesn't have any parameter 
output_layer_n.data = TransformationFunction(output_layer_n.data)
```

So how should I go about implementing it? What I want is not to take gradient accounted for `TransformationFunction()` in my code.

Answer (score 2):

If you just don't want to compute gradients for your `TransformationFunction`, it is easiest to turn off gradient computation for all parameters involved in this computation by setting the [`requires_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#requires-grad) flag to `False`.

- ***[Excluding subgraphs from backward:](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#excluding-subgraphs-from-backward)***

  > If there’s a single input to an operation that requires gradient, its
  >   output will also require gradient. Conversely, only if all inputs
  >   don’t require gradient, the output also won’t require it. Backward
  >   computation is never performed in the subgraphs, where all Tensors
  >   didn’t require gradients.
  >
  > This is especially useful when you want to freeze part of your model,
  >   or you know in advance that you’re not going to use gradients w.r.t.
  >   some parameters. For example if you want to finetune a pretrained CNN,
  >   it’s enough to switch the `requires_grad` flags in the frozen base, and
  >   no intermediate buffers will be saved, until the computation gets to
  >   the last layer, where the affine transform will use weights that
  >   require gradient, and the output of the network will also require
  >   them.

Here is a small example which would do so:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# define layers
normal_layer = nn.Linear(5, 5)
TransformationFunction = nn.Linear(5, 5)
# disable gradient computation for parameters of TransformationFunction
# here weight and bias
TransformationFunction.weight.requires_grad = False
TransformationFunction.bias.requires_grad   = False

# input 
inp = torch.rand(1, 5)

# do computation
out = normal_layer(inp)
out = TransformationFunction(out)

# loss
loss = torch.sum(out)
# backward
loss.backward()

# gradient for l1
print('Gradients for "normal_layer"', normal_layer.weight.grad, normal_layer.bias.grad)
# gradient for l2
print('Gradients for "TransformationFunction"', TransformationFunction.weight.grad, TransformationFunction.bias.grad)
```

Output:

```
Gradients for "normal_layer" tensor([[0.1607, 0.0215, 0.0192, 0.2595, 0.0811],
        [0.0788, 0.0105, 0.0094, 0.1272, 0.0398],
        [0.1552, 0.0207, 0.0186, 0.2507, 0.0784],
        [0.1541, 0.0206, 0.0184, 0.2489, 0.0778],
        [0.2945, 0.0393, 0.0352, 0.4756, 0.1486]]) tensor([0.2975, 0.1458, 0.2874, 0.2853, 0.5452])
Gradients for "TransformationFunction" None None
```

I hope this is what you were looking for, if not please edit your question with more detail!

Comment: Although the parameters of TransformationFucttion are non-trainable, the transformation done by TransformationFunction will have its effect on the gradient computation for previous layers. Right ? I actually want to avoid this.

Comment: @random_28 Thanks for your reply. You are right, and I'm afraid there is no way out of the box to avoid this, at least for the following layers you will change the inputs and thus the gradients. There might be workarounds, but since I'm not exactly sure what you want to do it is difficult to find something suitable. Why do you do you want to make computations during training time which you don't want to include in the graph. Could explain what exactly you wan't to do? It would be great/helpful if you could supplement your question with a short working code example and your desired output.